# Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A=v^T$. Prove that $\| A \|_2=\| v\|_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

> Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A=v^T$. Prove that $\| A \|_2=\| v\|_2$

I know this question has already been posted, but its answer has not convinced me. The norm from $A$ is the matrix 2-norm, and the second is the standard euclidean vector 2-norm. Some auxiliary results that I thought could help are:

- $\| M \|_2 = \sqrt{\|M^TM\|_2}, \ A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$
- $\| M \|_2 = \lambda_{max}, \ M$ is a symmetric matrix

Comment: 1. Your second result should read "$M$ is a Hermitian matrix." 2. Please clarify what aspects of other answers did not satisfy you so that potential responders do not repeat the same mistakes.

Comment: Is $A=v^T$ a typo? It looks like a matrix is equal to a vector.

Comment: @xnor No, he is referring to the operator $2$-norm of the $1\times n$ matrix $A = v^T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will let $||\cdot||_2$ denote the operator $2$-norm and $|\cdot|_2$ denote the vector $2$-norm.

Let $A = v^T$. Then we have $$||A||_2 = \sqrt{||(v^T)^Tv^T||_2} = \sqrt{||vv^T||_2}.$$ $vv^T$ is a matrix with rank 1. Indeed, $(vv^T)x \in \mathrm{span}\{v\} \ \forall x \in\mathbb{R}^n$. This means that $vv^T$ only has a single nonzero eigenvalue and, since $vv^T$ is real and symmetric, it will be positive. We find this eigenvalue and eigenvector by inspection:
$$
(vv^T)v = |v|_2^2 v.
$$
Therefore $|v|_2^2$ is an eigenvalue of $vv^T$. By our previous argument, it is the only nonzero eigenvalue, and it is positive, so it is the largest eigenvalue of $vv^T$. Therefore, we have
$$
||v^T||_2 = \sqrt{||vv^T||_2} = \sqrt{|v|_2^2} = |v|_2.
$$

Comment: very clever approach! Could you explain me how the rank of $vv^T$ is related to the number of eigenvalues?

Comment: @Piero If for some non-zero $x$ you have $(vv^T)x=0$ it has eigenvalue of $0$. This happens if and only if $x$ is in the nullspace. So being rank one means only one non-zero eigenvalue is possible.

Comment: In general, the number of nonzero eigenvalues is not the rank of the matrix, but the dimension of the null space is equal to the dimension of the generalized eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda = 0$. Here, we have $\mathrm{rank}(vv^T)=1$, so by rank-nullity theorem, $\mathrm{dim}(N(vv^T)) = n-1$, so the dimension of the generalized eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda=0$ is $n-1$, meaning that there must be one dimension corresponding to a non-zero eigenvalue.

Comment: Another way to see this is that we could make an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ using $v$ as one of the basis elements, then every other basis vector $x$ would satisfy $v^Tx = 0$, by construction. Therefore we've found $n-1$ eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda = 0$ and the only direction left is $v$.

Comment: @whpowell96 So essentially, it decays from the fact that different eigenvectors are linearly independent, right? The number of eigenvalues, if there are any, is at most 1, otherwise it would exceed the dimension of the rank space.

Comment: Non-zero eigenvalues, yes.